# Is there an efficient method to compare product of elements of 2 different sets of random 1-digit natural numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have 2 sets of 1-digit random natural numbers -
Set 1 - {$\ a_1$,$\ a_2$,$\ a_3$.....$\ a_n$}
Set 2 - {$\ b_1$,$\ b_2$,$\ b_3$.....$\ b_n$ }

For example -
Set A - {1,9,8,4,6,7,4,3,2,4,9,8}
Set B - {8,4,5,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

How can we compare product of elements of set A ($\ a_1$* $\ a_2$ *$\ a_3$..... *$\ a_n$) and product of elements of set B ($\ b_1$ *$\ b_2$ *$\ b_3$..... *$\ b_n$) efficiently without actually calculating the products ?

Comment: Compare them how?  Can you give an example of the sort of thing you have in mind?

Comment: Note:  nothing in your question really makes sense...you speak about "sum" and 'product" but a general group only has one binary operation, not two.  If you are thinking about a specific situation, you should describe it.

Comment: @lulu no specific situation. Sum of all elements is a more efficient operation than product of the elements. If sum of the elements of both the groups can infer something about their products, then i will be able to deduce which group product is larger without actually multiplying all the elements. If this is possible then how ? And can there be other methods than deducing it from sum too.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense.  A general group hasn't got notions of "sum" and "product", just "product".  Nor has a general group got a notion of size so "larger" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Hold on, you may just be using the wrong words.  "Group" means something very specific to mathematicians but you might just be using it as a synonym for "collection".  Is that the case?  If so, then you need to tell us what the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are. I mean, are they integers?  Natural numbers?  Real numbers?  Positive reals?  Or what?

Comment: @lulu edited the question. Now does it make some sense ?

Comment: Yes.  You can take the logs of the elements and add them, though I'm not sure that saves you much. Otherwise...well, it's hard to say much.  If the sums are equal, then the one which is "less dispersed" will have the greater product (trusting that everything is positive).  But if the sums aren't equal then it gets hard to decide.

Comment: @lulu okay . Thanks !